# Allow Table cell to content to expand horizontally

Tags: javascript, html, css

Having specified table cell width  `<td style="width:100px">` when content width is more than 100px texts wraps to the next line.

How can we specify the cell width so that when content width is less than 100px, it should occupy 100px otherwise force the contents to expand horizontally.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use min-width:

```
<td style="min-width:100px">
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you need [`min-width`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/CSS/Properties/min-width)

```
<td style="min-width:100px">
```